# Convergence or divergence of the integral $\int_0^1 dx/\sin x $

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Is this Convergent or Divergent

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sin(x)}\mathrm dx $$

So little background to see if I am solid on this topic otherwise correct me please :)

To check for convergence I can look for a "bigger" function and compare if that is convergent, If yes then for sure the one in question is too. So if the "bigger" function is not convergent can we conclude that the function in question is divergent or do we have to check for divergence to? That is a "smaller" function which has to be divergent?

And for this question I have no Idea WHAT kind of function to compare with:/

Comment: Compare with $1/x$, for instance.

Comment: Is that something I can do for all trigonometrical functions of this kind? In that case we have a divergent function.

Comment: I cannot think of universal rules. But here the "issue" is near $0$, where our function is "big." We need to ask "how big," by comparing with a function that has known behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Is this Convergent or Divergent* ?

Yes! :-)

> *I have no Idea WHAT kind of function to compare with:/*

**Hint:** $\sin x\sim x$ for $x\to0$.

Comment: Of course! That has been taught with limits!  But For Cos x instead of sin x, how do we do then? And also the background I gave, how do  I do when the function doesn't converge? Conclude that it is Divergent?

Comment: @Ara: $\cos x$ is never $0$ for $x\in(0,1)$, so the integral converges. However, $\cos\dfrac\pi2=0$, for instance, so if one were to ask you to determine the convergence or divergence of $\dfrac1{\cos x}$ on $\bigg(0,\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$, for example, then let $t=\dfrac\pi2-x$, and use the fact that $\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2-t\bigg)=\sin t$.

Comment: Ahh... That was clever thinking!

Comment: To elaborate on the $\sim$: It is valid to say that, if $lim_{x \rightarrow 0}f(x)/g(x) = 1$, and $f,g$ are continuous on $(0,a]$, then $int_0^a f(x)dx$ converges if and only if $int_0^ag(x)dx$ converges. In this example, $f(x) = 1/sin(x)$, $g(x) = 1/x$. The reason I like this comparison test is that you don't have to fuss with any inequalities.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following facts to find proper values of $A$ as well. Maybe it helps you for other integrands:

> Let $\lim_{x\to a^+}~(x-a)^pf(x)=A$. Then:
>
> - If $p<1$ and $A$ is finite then $\int_a^bfdx$ converges.
> - If $p\ge1$ and $A\neq0$ or $A=\infty$ then $\int_a^bfdx$ diverges.

Now, you can see that why @Lucian's short hint can guide you. Note that in above points $f(x)$ is unbounded only at the lower bound $a$.

Comment: Okey, I see. Haven't seen that in my textbook. I am supposed to use comparison test.

Comment: @Ara: This is a consequence of that test. See it again! :-)

Comment: So in the case you are showing we have "a" that is interesting. But if we where to have "b" that interest us. Can I just change the "a":s with "b":s? And use the same method?

Comment: @Ara: I that case you should consider `(b-x)^pf(x)`, `x->b^-`

Comment: Okey got it, I have posted an other question on the same topic :)

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$\frac{1}{{\sin x}}:\frac{1}{x} = \frac{x}{{\sin x}} = \frac{1}{{\sin x/x}} \to 1$$
as $x\to 0^+$. In other word, $\frac{1}{\sin x}\sim \frac{1}{x}$ as $x\to 0^+$. But, it is well known that $\int_0^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$ is divergent. So, we conclude that $\int_0^1 {\frac{1}{{\sin x}}dx}$ is divergent.